# Vue Test Utils: how to pass Vuelidate validation rules to child components?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils, vuelidate

while trying to write a `component test` by using `vue test utils`, testing interaction between child components and stuff, I am stuck due to usage of Vuelidate from child components. Below is an example simplified:

```
// parent component code

<template>
   <div>
      <childA />
   </div>
</template>
```

```
//childA code

<template>
   <input v-model="value" />
</template>

<script>
   ...
   validations: {
      value: {
         required
      }
   }
...
</script>
```

```
// parent component test
...
const wrapper = mount(MyParentComponent, {
   ...,
   components: {
      childA,
   },
   validations: {
      value: required
   },
   ...
})
```

I have tried to find a solution out there that I could mount (note here that I WANT to mount also the child components, so `shallow-mount` is not what I look for) the child component, with it's respective Vuelidate validation rules, but I still haven't found any solution.

Instead, my test gives me errors like:

```
Cannot read property `value` of undefined
```

which makes sense, since the test cannot access the child component's `$v` instance.

Has anyone achieved it so far?

Comment: Maybe is it a stupid question but did you mock the data in your test file ?

Comment: Can you validate my question ? :)

Answer (score 2):

For answering your question and after i've did some test i believe you missed the `data` part inside your `mount`

1. `mount`: render child components
2. `shallowMount`: doesn't render child components

`MyParentComponent` need to have in the options the structure of you're child component so this is why he is returning the error

And i saw that you're passing the import of your component directly but don't forget that your test folder is outside of your `src` folder

`import ChildA from "@/components/ChildA";`

will not work instead i propose to use absolute path directly to import your child component or use a configuration to resolve them

```js
    const wrapper = mount(MyParentComponent, {
      data() {
        return {
          value: null
        }
      },
      components: {
        ChildA: () => import('../../src/components/ChildA'),
      },
      validations: {
        value: required
      },
    })
```